# Intel integrated GPU not recognized

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, 22.10

CPU: Intel 12900k (Alder Lake - 12th Gen)
Video card: Nvidia RTX 3080
MOtherboard: MSI MEG Z690 Unifiy-X
O/S: Ubuntu 22.10

System does not see the Intel integrated GPU

> $ lspci -v |grep -A8 VGA
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA
> Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1) (prog-if
> 00 [VGA controller])

I want to have both the Nvidia GPU and Intel GPU (QSV) available for h/w video encoding.
I have confirmed that ReBar is enabled at the bios, which is a requirement per Intel.  Motherboard bios is latest available at time of posting.

Intel's website does not list a driver for Ubuntu 22.10.

> $ apt-cache search linux-image-5
>
> linux-image-5.17.0-1003-oem - Signed kernel image OEM

Do I need to update the Linux kernel?  Or am I missing a package?

Comment: Few mother boards support simultaneous use of igpu and gpu. The marketing materials and manual do not indicate that this board supports simultaneous use of igpu and gpu. Could you check in the bios if both gpus are enabled? Most likely the igpu will be automatically disabled to free pcie lanes

Comment: using 2 GPU is common.  The command "sudo prime-select" is used to switch between two.  But, in my case, I currently unable to get the intel GPU to show up. lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA" should show both the Nvidia and the Intel GPUs but only shows the Nvidia.

Answer (score 2):

After tons of research and hours on support with the motherboard manufacture MSI), it was determined that the motherboard (Z690 Unify X) does not support both then intel integrated GPU (iGPU) and the graphics card.  The motherboard does not have a video output jack (HDMI, displayport, etc), so it disables the Intel 770 UHD GPU (iGPU).

There is not a setting in the bios on this motherboard to override that issue.  The only resolution is to replace the motherboard with a different model.

@J. Starnes comment above got me headed in the right direction - thank you for the help.  I have ordered a new motherboard to resolve the issue.

I was able to reproduce the problem in both windows and Ubuntu - so the issue was not O/S specific.

Comment: I installed a new motherboard today and was able to confirm the theory.  With the new board, I have access to the Intel integrated GPU.  Thanks again to J. Starnes for the direction.

Comment: Which motherboard did you get?

Comment: MSI Z690 Ace. It solved the problem.